# Versioned associations using vestal_versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, associations, vestal-versions

I'd like to be sure if vestal_versions does support versioned associations (it seems like it doesn't) before switching out to another versioning gem that can support versioned associations e.g => [has_versioning](http://github.com/kkurach/has_versioning). I haven't looked at the code yet but I couldn't find anything related with versioned associations from the readme file or the issue section on github. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(At the moment of writing this) There is an [associations branch](http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions/tree/associations) in the official [vestal_versions](http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) repository, It is still a basic idea and isn't merged yet in the master branch. So I decided to go with another versioning gem, specifically [acts_as_revisable](http://github.com/rich/acts_as_revisable) following the instructions in [this](http://withoutscope.com/2009/5/12/simple-association-versioning-with-acts_as_revisable) blog post.

Comment: it would be nice, if you share the "[an]other versioning gem" with the rest of us

Comment: I tried with `has_versioning` but it blew up my app finders (for all models, even if they are not versioned) so I decided to use `acts_as_revisable` based on this post: http://withoutscope.com/2009/5/12/simple-association-versioning-with-acts_as_revisable the bad thing: it's not a built-in gem feature and isn't tested yet, the good thing: you can try out a demo http://github.com/rich/aar-demo-1 and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something that appears to be very close to your needs. But I don't need to revert the associated objects, just to record them. I was thinking of handle it in a nosql way. So I can save the model version and the associations would be embedded documents.

So I can compare versions in a more comprehensive way. Right now I use paper_trail, but as it can't handle associations, it's not possible to store the tags associated to a model and see how it changes through time.

Comment: Mongoid or Mongomapper can handle it pretty sweet with embedded documents, in my case the app is already working with AR and the change to Mongodb is considerable (in terms of time), I tried paper_trail but as you said it doesn't handle associations, maybe you should check this post http://withoutscope.com/2009/5/12/simple-association-versioning-with-acts_as_revisable

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm currently using paper_trail but, as you said, it doesn't handle associations until now. I'll try something (maybe from scratch) because it would only change 1 model, so it won't be a big deal.