# Tracking changes on instances of a class and their associations - thoughts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auditing

I have a class Question which has a lot of assocated models.  On one page on my app i list a summary of all the current questions, with various info from associated records.  Ultimately this is a hash of values that i then just print out into a csv-style row (i'll call this the 'row hash' from hereon)

I now have a requirement to only show the *changes* to questions (or their associated data) over a given period.  I'm currently deliberating the best way to do this.  Here's some ideas i've had so far, i'd welcome any feedback, thoughts, suggestions etc.

1) Approach 1 - acts_as_audited
This was my first thought as i've used this before in other apps.  The porblem with aaa though is that it only tracks changes to the record's data (ie it doesn't care if the associations change).  So, i could audit all of the associated records as well but then trying to piece together what had changed by tying different audit records together sounds like a nightmare.

2) Save the old and new hash out into serialized fields: ie
  - when someone goes to the question/edit page, i calculate the current row hash and save it in a serialized field "old_data" in the question table.  Then after they save the question i calculate the new current row hash and save it into a serialized field "new_data" in the question table.  Also, i compare the two serialized hashes and save the differences into another serialized hash field 'changes'.  Now to do my report i just look for questions updated in the last x days and output their changes data.

3) make a view
  - i make a view which corresponds to the data that i want to output (ie that amalgamates all the data that i pull into my report).  Then i track changes to the view - somehow.  I'm not sure how exactly i would do that.

I'm leaning towards option 2 right now.

Any other thoughts/comments?  grateful for any suggestions - max.

Answer (score 1):

So, like you said, you only want to show changes to the records between time x and time y, right? This would seem perfect to me using the acts_as_audited plugin because you end up with a table of changes, right? So make a has_many_through association from Question to all these related tables, then search it for related changes, where date created is after time X. This would return a list of changes. From there, you could connect this list back to the parent object if you need to, or whatever - but it in the end seems like a more reasonable thing to search. You're not looking for a list of related objects, after all, you're looking for a list of changes, so having a table of changes seems a reasonable way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had a similar problem, check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191042/versioned-associations-using-vestal-versions). If you can, go with Mongoid or Mongomapper, embedded versioned documents are sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  I ended up rolling my own solution because what i really needed to do was to capture changes in the results of various methods called on the object, some of which involved associated objects.  I wasn't so much interested in the associated objects as (for example) a text string generated as a result of looking at a few different associated objects.  I had methods to do all of this already so i really just needed to track changes in the results of calling these methods.

None of the plugins i saw could really do that simply and effectively, so i ended making a table called states which just holds a serialized hash with results of all of these method calls.  This gets saved when the record is altered and saved or when any of the relevant associated objects get altered and saved.  Then i have some methods to return the differences between different saved state records.  It works well for my needs.  Thanks very much for your advice anyway.